# S3 node module, attempting to upload file gives ENETUNREACH error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to my Amazon S3 bucket but I'm getting an ENETUNREACH error. I do have permissions to upload/delete files for my buckets and also edited the CORS configuration to allow POST/GET requests from all origins. I'm thinking it might be a faulty key(s) that I received from someone. What is a good way to test if the keys I have are valid if that happens to be the issue?

Code below:

```
var s3 = require('s3');

/* Create a client for uploading or deleting files */
var client = s3.createClient({
    maxAsyncS3: 20,     // this is the default 
    s3RetryCount: 3,    // this is the default 
    s3RetryDelay: 1000, // this is the default 
    multipartUploadThreshold: 20971520, // this is the default (20 MB) 
    multipartUploadSize: 15728640, // this is the default (15 MB)
    s3Options: {
        accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxx',
        secretAccesskey: 'xxxxxxxx',
        region: 'xxxxxxxx'
    },
});

exports.uploadFile = function(fileName, bucket){
    console.log('Uploading File: ' +fileName+'\nBucket: ' +bucket);

    var params = {
        localFile: fileName, 

        s3Params: {
          Bucket: bucket,
          Key: 'testfile',
        },
    };

    var uploader = client.uploadFile(params);
    uploader.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error("unable to upload:", err.stack);

    });

    uploader.on('progress', function() {
        console.log("progress", uploader.progressMd5Amount, uploader.progressAmount, uploader.progressTotal);
    });

    uploader.on('end', function() {
        console.log("done uploading");
    });
};
```

Console log when trying to upload a txt small file:

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeCKO.png)

Comment: Do `console.log(client)` and post the output.

Comment: `ENETUNREACH` means that the network for the address you're trying to connect to is not reachable from that system. 169.x.x.x is not a valid routeable address. Are you able to successfully ping your s3 hostname/address from the command prompt?

Comment: @peteb http://puu.sh/nBGPQ/8893b53224.png

Comment: ping `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` like @mscdex suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled IIS services to fix my error.